# Allow only certain UDIDs for Enterprise App

Tags: ios, xcode

I have been developing an app for my company for quite some time now, and the issue I run into is distribution. I used to sign and install everything myself, but doing that 5-6 times a day gets really frustrating.

I have been looking at the Enterprise Developer Program and I was wondering if I can restrict the App access only to certain devices? Meaning, I would still like to require the tester's UDID. I do understand that I could do that with TestFlight, but I don't want the tester to sign up for anything and I need more than 100 devices.

I would appreciate any help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1 Make sure you use the Enterprise program

2 Make sure you use Distribution certificate, not the Development one to build your application.

Comment: Ok, I will do that. Then only devices whose UDIDs are registered can install the app? And by any chance, do you know where the UDIDs would be saved?

Comment: you have made a mistake somewhere, I use enterprise program over the year and have no problem. Revoke your certificate, delete profile and recreate it again. Also check which profile you use in project settings.

Comment: I am in the DUNS application process right now, so I can't test it just yet. From what I understand though is that anyone could install the app through the enterprise program, and that's what I am trying to avoid. I want only certain devices to work. That's why I was wondering if I can store the allowed UDIDs somewhere.

Comment: tl;dr could I potentially require UDIDs for internal distribution as well?

Comment: You can use Development certificate to build you app. UDID will be required in this case.

Comment: Or you can add something like registration/authoorizaion to your app

Comment: That's a good idea, but even with an authorization there is no guarantee from leaking the app. Thanks about letting me know the with the Development certificate, the issue solely is that I don't want to build each app once we release a new version, because there will be around 300-400 testers.